# When taking union of two tables with VARCHAR columns, the resulting query expects type INT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, types, union

Over the past six months, two large views with nearly 100 columns have been created at an office where I work.  My SQL server is MS SQL Server 2008.

The two views pull data from two sources with two very different formats, so it isn't very practical to write it as a single view.  However, it is necessary to query both views at once, so I wrote a simple query:

```
CREATE VIEW Combined_View AS
SELECT * FROM View0
UNION
SELECT * FROM View1;
```

It sounds like a simple, solution, but I'm having a problem now.

Combined_View has a column called `Special`.  Up until today, View0.Special was always an empty string, while View1.Special is a nullable string with a few textual values.

I received instructions to modify `View0.Special` so that it would contain data from another table.  Simple, right?  Wrong!  After making the requested modification, and trying to select from the combined view, I see an error that says, "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' to data type int."

The above doesn't make any sense at all to me.  I can't understand how I could have told SQL to convert this value to an integer, and yes, I did check that the value occurs in `View0.Special`.

Trying to track down the problem, I queried `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WITH

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'View%' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Special';
```

The results of this query are strange.

`View0.Special` is VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL.

`View1.Special` is VARCHAR(20) NULL.

`Combined_View.Special` is INT NOT NULL.

I read this to indicate that SQL somehow inferred that the UNION of two different columns should have type `INT`, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that the ordinal position of columns in both views line-up.
I suspect this is what's happening (just using 3 columns to illustrate my point)

```
CREATE VIEW Combined_View AS
SELECT 
,col1
,Special
,col3 FROM View0
UNION
SELECT 
Special
,col1
,col3
 FROM View1;
```

Now, if col1 & col3 are of `int` type, the above query is trying to fit view1.special into view0.col1 and causes issues with conversion.
By asking you to make sure the columns line up correctly, what I mean is this:

```
    CREATE VIEW Combined_View AS
    SELECT 
    ,col1
    ,Special
    ,col3 FROM View0
    UNION
    SELECT 
   col1
    ,Special
    ,col3
     FROM View1;
```